# import of the hammer library

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the hammer library to control the swipe events inside my code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<body class="ind2">
//Other code ....
```

and this a sample from the main.js file:

```
var element = document.getElementById('ind2');
        var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("swipedown", function(event) {
            alert("ffffg");
        });
```

The problem is that when I run my application, I always got this error message;

> js/main.js (38) :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Hammer

What's wrong? Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: use the code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: check the path of hammer.js file... i think its `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>`

Comment: I correct the mistake, but another one is shown:
**js/hammer.js (8) :TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.addEventListener')**